# How to split a Long into two Ints in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How can I split a Long (64bit) into two Integer (32bit) in Kotlin?

I've tried something like this but it doesn't seem to be doing it:

```
val id = Integer.MAX_VALUE.toLong() + 2000
val a = id.toInt()
val b = (id shr 32).toInt()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is working fine. Note that `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `0x7FFFFFFF`, when you add `2000`, it becomes `0x800007CF`, which is still within 32-bit, but overflow to the negative number range when interpreted as 32-bit signed integer. Therefore `a` is a negative `Int` and `b` is `0`